# How to disable JWT Authorization on specific API endpoints (Java)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have API endpoints configured for JWT Authorization:

```
 @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<EsgJwtAuth> esgJwtAuthBean() {
    EsgJwtAuth esgJwtAuth;
    try {
      HashMap<String, String> myConf = new HashMap<>();
      myConf.put("header", "Authorization");
      myConf.put("jwksUrl", jwksUrl);
      myConf.put("jwksCacheSize", jwksCacheSize);
      myConf.put("jwksExpiresIn", jwksExpiresIn);
      myConf.put("jwksRateLimitSize", jwksRateLimitSize);
      myConf.put("jwksRateLimitRefillRate", jwksRateLimitRefillRate);
      esgJwtAuth = new EsgJwtAuth(myConf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      esgJwtAuth = new EsgJwtAuth();
    }

    FilterRegistrationBean<EsgJwtAuth> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(esgJwtAuth);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/a/*");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/b/*");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/c/*");
    return registrationBean;
  }
```

Now, i wanted to make `/a/noauth` to not require a JWT authorization. But for other endpoints such as `/a/withauth/`, `/a/*` i want it to require JWT authorization (as registered on the FilterRegistrationBean)

So far, i tried extending my class with `OncePerRequestFilter` and implemented the ff codes:

```
 @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    List<String> excludeUrlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    excludeUrlPatterns.add("/a/noauth/");
    excludeUrlPatterns.add("/b/noauth/");

    return excludeUrlPatterns.stream()
        .anyMatch(exclude -> request.getRequestURI().contains(exclude));
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

But when i run a request for `/a/noauth` **without** the `Header: <JWT token>`, it is ***Unauthorized***. How to allow it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do think that your `excludeUrlPatterns` `List` contains the wrong values (i.e. put `/a/noauth` instead of `/a/noauth/`).

I would rather suggest to use the `AntPathMatcher` class to check your excluding patterns. See below a naive implementation:

```
private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    List<String> excludeUrlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    excludeUrlPatterns.add("/a/noauth");
    excludeUrlPatterns.add("/b/noauth");

    return excludeUrlPatterns.stream()
        .anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getRequestURI()));
}
```

Comment: It looks like `AntPathMatcher` is not thread-safe. Move the declaration in your method to make it thread-safe.